# How can I display all anchor categories even with no result (empty category) in Magento?

Tags: magento, layered-navigation

How can I display all anchor categories in Magento (1.9.0.1) even with no result (empty category) as for attribute product?

As default behavior when I set "anchor" a category, this is shown in "Shopping by" section only if is no empty. I'ld like to show all categories.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please include code samples or screenshots to visualize the problem.

Comment: Done, screenshot posted.

Comment: When using ManaDev extension, this functionality is included out-of-the-box. See http://www.manadev.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirty & fast way:

Edit: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php:170

```
if ($category->getIsActive() && $category->getProductCount()) {
```

And remove `&& $category->getProductCount()`.

More clean & right way is rewrite entire module extending core class.

Comment: Standard "Don't edit the core" message coming from me! Override it or create your own plugin!